# Динамические inline формы Django

Tags: django, form, django-admin

Нужно было добавить inline форму в зависимости от значения в основном объекте. Реализовал сначала через `get_inlines`  с сигналами, но при смене значения, влияющего на существование/отсутсвие инлайна, появлялась ошибка, связанная с отсутсвие `management_form`. Сосбственно пробелема в реализации динамического инлайна в зависимости от наличия того или иного значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и было сказано ранее, реализация была через `get_inlines`. Для удобства, вынес подбор доп.инлайнов в отдельный метод

```
    def get_inlines(self, request, obj):
        inlines = super().get_inlines(request, obj)
        ex_inlines = self.get_extra_inlines(request, obj)

        return inlines + ex_inlines


    def get_extra_inlines(self, request, obj):
        ex_inlines = []

        for receiver, response in mailing_inlines_signal.send_robust(sender=self.model, modeladmin=self, request=request, obj=obj):
            if response:
                from django.contrib.admin.options import InlineModelAdmin
                if isinstance(response, InlineModelAdmin):
                    ex_inlines.append(response)
                elif isinstance(response, list) or isinstance(response, tuple):
                    ex_inlines += list(response)
                    
        return ex_inlines
```

Проблема с получением инлайнов была решена получением текущего значения поля из модели, полученной из бд

```
@receiver(mailing_inlines_signal, sender=MailingRule, dispatch_uid='integrations.mailing.MailingRule.extra_inlines')
def get_mailing_rule_extra_inline(sender, modeladmin, request, obj: MailingRule, **kwargs):
    order_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Order)
    try:
        real_object = MailingRule.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
    except MailingRule.DoesNotExist:
        real_object = None
    inlines = []
    if real_object and real_object.template.for_model_only == order_ct:
        from integrations.admin import OrderMailingRuleInline
        inlines.append(OrderMailingRuleInline)

    return inlines
```

Собственно, на этом проблема решена. Но мне также нужно было, чтобы пользователю сообщали, что нужно добавить значение в инлайн форму, если она не заполнена (связь `OneToOne`). Это решил другим сигналом в `_changeform_view` и сигналом, которые добавляет сообщение для пользователя

```
    def _changeform_view(self, request, object_id, form_url, extra_context):
        response = super()._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
        if 'GET' in request.method:
            try:
                obj = self.model.objects.get(pk=object_id)
                mailing_post_save.send(sender=MailingRule, instance=obj, request=request)
            except self.model.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return response


@receiver(mailing_post_save, sender=MailingRule, dispatch_uid='integrations.mailing.MailingRule.mailing_post_save')
def notify_user_in_admin(sender, instance: MailingRule, request, **kwargs):
    """Уведомление
    """
    order_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Order)
    if instance.template.for_model_only == order_ct and not OrderMailingRule.objects.filter(rule=instance).exists():
        from django.contrib import messages
        messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, _('Link mailing rule with order event'))
```

PS:  Надеюсь кому нибудь в будущем это поможет.

PSS: Если будут рекомендации по улучшению ответа, приму к сведению и постараюсь улучшить ответ